# Python Kivy Image rotate by event

Tags: python, image, sockets, rotation, kivy

Please help rotate the image by event in the `def read_sok():` function.

Accessing the `TestPY().update()` does not rotate the image.
the `print("update")` string is executed

the angle to rotate the image is sent from the server

the app is being developed to simulate a switch device

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Rotate
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PopMatrix, PushMatrix

# Socket client example in python

import socket
import sys
import threading

host = '192.168.12.95'
port = 2000  # web

a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

# create socket
print('# Creating socket')
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print('Failed to create socket')
    sys.exit()

print('# Getting remote IP address')
try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
except socket.gaierror:
    print('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()

# Connect to remote server
print('# Connecting to server, ' + host + ' (' + remote_ip + ')')
s.connect((remote_ip, port))

# Send data to remote server
print('# Sending data to server')
request = "hello server"

try:
    s.sendall(request.encode('utf-8'))
except socket.error:
    print('Send failed')
    sys.exit()

# Receive data
print('# Receive data from server')
reply = s.recv(4096)

print(reply)


def read_sok():
    global a, b, c
    while 1:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        b = int(data.decode('utf-8'))
        TestPY().update()


potok = threading.Thread(target=read_sok)
potok.start()


class TestKV(Image):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)


Builder.load_string('''
<TestPY>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin: root.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
''')


class TestPY(Image):
    global a, b, c
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestPY, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.x = x -- not necessary, x is a property and will be handled by super()
        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rot = Rotate()
            self.rot.angle = 0
            self.rot.origin = self.center
            self.rot.axis = (0, 0, 1)

        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.rot.angle = b

    def update(self):
        self.rot.angle = b
        print("update")

    def dd(self):
        rot.angle = b
        print("dd")


class MainWidget(Widget):
    # this is the main widget that contains the game.

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.all_sprites = []

        self.k = TestKV(source="dd1.png", x=10, size=(400, 400))
        self.add_widget(self.k)

        self.p = TestPY(source="dd2.png", x=10, size=(400, 400))
        self.add_widget(self.p)


class TheApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        app = MainWidget()
        parent.add_widget(app)
        return parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheApp().run()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEKXL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it happens because you have the angle of rotation defined in 'init'. While you are running 'TestPY().update()' at first it creates new object of the class, rotates it to 0°, and then launches update method, when rotation is over.

You can try to define your angle in the init method, maybe that'll work:

```
while 1:
    ...
    TestPY(b)


class TestPY(Image):
    ...
    def __init__(self, b, **kwargs):
        super(TestPY, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rot = Rotate()
            self.rot.angle = b
            self.rot.origin = self.center
            self.rot.axis = (0, 0, 1)
```

Or you can define your angle as NumericProperty() and don't create new instances of a class in limitless loop. So you can try this:

```
tp = TestPY()
while 1:
    ...
    tp.update(b)


class TestPY(Image):
    ...
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestPY, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rot = Rotate()
            self.rot.angle = self.b
            self.rot.origin = self.center
            self.rot.axis = (0, 0, 1)

    self.b = NumericProperty()

    def update(self, b):
        self.b = b
        print("update")
```

Comment: thanks for the tips. but I can't do it anyway. maybe if you have time you download .7z here. http://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread2576862.html#taglist